# Does Firebase queue writes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question, does firebase queue writes?

```
var hopperRef = usersRef.child("gracehop");
hopperRef.update({
  "nickname": "Amazing Grace",
  "age":"21",
  "nick":"Andrew",
  "players":"2"
});
```

Will 'players' get pushed last? How do the writes work, the reason for this question is because if I do a firebase trigger on hopperRef I want to make sure all the data is there before my trigger happens.

Comment: It will all happen at once, unless you do something like: `hopperRef.child("age").setValue(30)` which will change an individual child.

Comment: Thanks George! @George_E_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single call to `update()` causes a single write to occur of all the data you pass to it.  Each field does not write separately.

Comment: Thanks Doug! So if I have an onCreate trigger on hopperRef I can assume all the data is there. This is clearly different than me doing a .set("nick") and right after a .set("players"). in that case players gets pushed last correct?